# Memlock and HugePages in Oracle database, which value to set?

Tags: oracle, installation

[Oracle says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/ladbi/checking-resource-limits-for-oracle-software-installation-users.html#GUID-293874BD-8069-470F-BEBF-A77C06618D5A):

> The value of the memlock should be at least 90 percent of the current
> RAM when HugePages memory is enabled and at least 3145728 KB (3 GB)
> when HugePages memory is disabled.

But the MOS [Oracle Linux: What is Memlock and How to Calculate the Values for Memlock? (Doc ID 2511230.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?_afrLoop=413310280053374&id=2511230.1) show this formule:

For that following calculation:

> Number Hugepages * Hugepagesize = minimum Memlock
>
> Following example:
>
> 20480 * 2048 = 41943040
>
> vi /etc/security/limits.conf
>
> oracle soft memlock 41943040
> oracle hard memlock 41943040

Should we considerer `90% of available ram` or `Hugepages * Hugepagesize?`

Also, the doc says "at least 3145728 KB (3 GB) when HugePages memory is disabled". Let's say our server has 200gb memory, this "at least" is
still applicable?